# Append data in 2 dimensional array through for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array. I have created two nested loops to append data to this array, but I am getting error. The error is ''numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append''. Any help to overcome this error is appreciated.

Thanks

```
arr1 = np.zeros((1000,4))
for j in range(0,4,1):
   for i in range(0,1000,1):
      x = rho * R * T  # temperature changes for each iteration
      arr1[i][j].append(x)
```

Comment: `arr1[i][j]` is selecting a single value, which you are then trying to append to, throwing the error. Try `print(arr1[i][j])` to see this in action

Comment: Use `arr1[i][j] = x`, if you want to assign to a position.

Comment: @Austin, yes it workes but the values get added from 1st row. So 0th row is "NaN". Any suggestions for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The function call is not represented as a member function of numpy array. This means you can not call the function on a numpy object as you did: object.append(...) What you should do is

np.append(object, object2)

object2 will be appended to object

so you should do

```
array = np.append(array, value, axis=0 or 1)
```

You can read about it in the documentation. You can also pass the axis along which the values will be appended.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html